# cordova-based application is not seen in iOS phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova-2.0.0

I am trying to develop a first app using cordova. I followed the instruction from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-xcode-for-ios.html, but when I try to create a project in Xcode `cordova-based application` is not found in `choose a template for your new project`.

Xcode is `xcode_4.4.3` and cordova is `cordova-2.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Xcode templates are no longer available for in Cordova since version 2.0:

http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/improvements-in-cordova-2-0-0-for-ios/